# Kernel mode access to user space variable

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I am writing a kernel function foo where it takes a structure pointer as its parameter

```
void foo(struct struct1 *param)
{

    if(param!=NULL)
    {
        if(param->param1!=NULL)
        {
            if(param->param1->bool_value)
                Some code
        }
    }
    some code
}
```

This function runs in the process context. 
I got a crash at this line in the above function. `if(param->param1->bool_value)`. 
This crash was a one time crash and it never occured again.

The BADVA address points to a user space address. Is this address the address of param1->bool_value? And if so, can a kernel mode code access this address for reading without using copy_from_user?

Comment: It smells like a bad pointer.

Comment: What is the definition/initialization of these two structures?

Comment: Never mind about some code,. Its just the condition checks that had executed before the crash. 
 struct param1 { bool bool_value; //first declared in param1
                 more boolean values};
struct param contains param1 structure in its definition

Comment: I'm pretty sure that kernel crash log says everything. Can you paste it?

Comment: Referring your edit: A pointer referencing memory (not pointing to NULL) does not necessarily points to a valid ("valid" in the context of the calling process) memory address .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure (using locks) that the structure does not get modified from under you between the test and the access? Perhaps you could use

```
void foo(struct somestruct *const param)
{
    if (param) {
        struct otherstruct *const param1 = param->param1;

        if (param1 && param1->bool_value) {
            /* Do stuff */
        }
    }
}
```

Note that C specifies short-circuit logic for `&&`, so if `param1` is NULL in the innermost test, `param1` will **not** be dereferenced.

This kind of access pattern (without the outermost `if (param)`) is very common in the Linux kernel. The only thing to notice is that discarding `param1` must still be protected by some kind of a lock, so that it is not freed while some other CPU is accessing it still (via a cached pointer).

Comment: Thanks.This case,  param1 is not null and hence param1->bool_value is also not. This, I am sure from the register dump.

Comment: @Sibi: Is it possible another CPU modifies `param1` (within the `param` structure)? If so, then `param1` might have been accessed mid-update; i.e. partially old and partially new value. It might have to straddle a cacheline boundary for that to happen, though.

Comment: Mine is a uniprocessor environment.

Comment: @Sibi: If the kernel is preemptible, then your kernel code may be interrupted by anything the kernel deems more important. Was the second bit of the address of `param1` set? (ie. `address % 4` == 2) If it was, then it is possible your code modifying `param1` was pre-empted midway through the pointer change, I think. And if it really was just an one-off occurrence, it could have been something as simple as a high-energy particle flipping just the right bit. It is an extremely rare occurrence, but it does happen. Oh, and no closed source drivers (tainted kernel), I hope?

Comment: The kernel crash says Its tainted. 
From ur question, How does it matter with the second bit of the address. The address of our concern is 00008683. Ah. .U are right I guess, this address falls in user region. Kernel mode operation is not allowed to access user addresses, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the pointer was garbled. I've seen closed-source drivers scribble over random memory, so having a tainted kernel is a big red flag for me; they crash in mysterious ways. Just my opinion, though. Having an odd address for a pointer to a pointer looks peculiar on x86; I'd expect it to be divisible by four. And you're right, kernel code is expected to use `copy_from`/`to_user()` to access userspace. (I don't remember if it does anything special on plain x86 (no PAE etc.), though.)

Answer (score 2):

`param->param1` may be uninitialised or have been over-written.

When you initialise `struct1`, do you always set its members to NULL?  If you don't, your problem may be with use of uninitialised data and will be relatively straightforward to deal with.  If you do always initialise to NULL, some other code may have over-written the member; this would be harder to diagnose.

Comment: Yes. the structure is cleared out to zero at initialization. What are the ways to diagnose in the other case?

Comment: If you can run gdb, you could try setting a [watchpoint](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_30.html) when the address of param->param1 changes.  If you can't run a debugger, you might have to resort to scattering checks throughout your code to gradually narrow down the problem area.

Comment: Happened only once and its a large piece of code to do a scatter check.  :(  Can you point me to an example of this 'overwriting the member' - the second case of your answer. ?

Comment: Any code which sets/copies/moves memory could be at fault if it writes more memory than the destination had allocated.

Comment: Nominal Animal's suggestion to check for thread safety is also very good.  If your code is multi-threaded, are you sure that another thread isn't modifying your struct1 instance while your foo function is running.

Comment: Yea. Nice point. But my module here can not be multithreaded.

Comment: @Sibi: You have locks to ensure that? Kernel happily runs the same code on multiple CPUs (or cores or hyperthreads) simultaneously, unless you prevent that with some form of locking.